# What type of parameters should be in a custom initializer?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, subclass

When adding a custom initializer to a subclass, are there any rules as to what kind of parameters it should take? As an example, is there a particular reason why UIView doesn't have the initializer below, and would there be any argument for **not** adding it to a custom subclass of UIView?

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor;
```

I haven't been able to find an answer to this on the web, so I hope that some of you can enlighten me.

Comment: No, there aren't really any rules about the required parameters.  Generally you add whatever makes it easiest to use or whatever parameters *must* be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anything in there. But then you can add so many that it becomes ridiculous...

```
initWithFrame:backgroundColor:tintColor:alpha:hidden:userTouchEnabled:...
```

It really depends on what you're using the subclass for.

For instance, you might create a `PlayingCardView` subclass. This is going to have certain properties... `suit`, `faceValue`. Because every card **MUST** have a suit and face value it makes sense to put these into the init method.

So it would be sensible to create an initialiser...

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuit:(Suit *)suit faceValue:(FaceValue *)faceValue;
```

because every card has to have a suit and a face value.

Equally, you could have another property `backImage` to set the image on the "back" of the card. So you could have...

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuit:(Suit *)suit faceValue:(FaceValue *)faceValue backImage:(UIImage *)backImage;
```

Now you can use one of two initialisers. One for the "default" back image the other to set a custom back image.

Then you get into **designated initialisers** in this case, it would be preferable not to have repeated code in both init methods so you would make the first method like this...

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuit:(Suit *)suit faceValue:(FaceValue *)faceValue
{
    UIImage *defaultBackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultCardImage"];

    return [self initWithSuit:suit faceValue:faceValue backImage:defaultBackImage];
}
```

And the **designated initialiser** would do all the actual setting up of the card.

In reality though, there is no fixed way and no correct way of doing this and it can take a while to find a pattern that you find easiest/best to use.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom initializer can take any parameter you want to. As any other class, UIView define some let's say basic behaviour, so if you need any other behaviour you are free to add it using a subclass for example. Don't complain that UIView or any other classes don't have  methods that you think would be good for them to have.

I would recomend you not write a custom initializer which has many arguments because it increase the complexity. Think exactly what is needed for that classes to be initalized correctly.